# SSD drive erase with 7 pas DoD 5220.22-M

Tags: ssd, disk-management, nvme, secure-erase

On conventional hard disks, I was using DOD Short /3 pass and DOD 5220 7 pass. This method can be used on SSD and NVMe drives as well?
I mean it will not affect the disk performance?
Or there is hdpram that can ONLY be used for SSD or nvm-cli for NVMe disks?

[image]